# Restart on crash script check

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to make a shell script that checks to see if 2 different processes are running and to restart them if they aren't. I just want to keep it simple.
Is this the correct way because it doesn't look like the 2nd part is working...

```
trap "exit" SIGINT

while true :
do
  ./stream.sh
  echo "Stream has Crashed"
done


trap "exit" SIGINT

while true :
do
  ./current_song.sh
  echo "Current Song has Crashed"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues:

- The script never gets beyond the first `done` and this is the main reason the second part is not working.
- There is no [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
- `while true :` is weird. Both `true` and `:` are builtins in Bash, [both return true](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34678/108618). Sole `while true` would be enough, the same with `while :`. It seems you wanted([?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming)) to use both variants at the same time and this piece of code even "works", i.e. it doesn't fail. It doesn't fail because this `:` of yours is not a builtin I mentioned; it's an argument to the `true` command. `true` discards its command line arguments. `true :` or `true almost anything` is equivalent to `true`, so your `while true :` works like `while true`.

A way to keep restarting many separate processes from one script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "kill 0" SIGINT

while :; do process1; done &
while :; do process2; done &
# ...
while :; do processN; done
```

This executes N `while` loops in separate shells (N-1 subshells and the main shell), so every single loop runs in parallel, independently. In your case the script may be:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "kill 0" SIGINT

while :
do
   ./stream.sh
   echo "Stream has Crashed"
done &

while :
do
   ./current_song.sh
   echo "Current Song has Crashed"
done
```

The trap kills (tries to kill) all the descendants thanks to [this `kill 0` trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67532/108618):

> All processes in the current process group are signaled